# Run-time error 9

Tags: arrays, vba, runtime-error

I'm really new at VBA and I've been trying all day on this one problem, so any help and tips are appreciated. I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)


Dim intArray(0, 9) As Integer
Dim strTarget As String
Dim blnFound As Boolean
Dim intRowIndex As Integer
Dim intColumnIndex As Integer
Dim intMatchIndex As Integer


For intRowIndex = 0 To 9
   intArray(intRowIndex, intColumnIndex) = Cells(1, Chr(65 + intRowIndex))
Next intRowIndex


strTarget = "Q"
  blnFound = False
For intRowIndex = 0 To 1
For intColumnIndex = 0 To 9
  If strTarget = intArray(intRowIndex, intColumnIndex) Then
     blnFound = True
     Exit For
  End If
Next intColumnIndex
  If blnFound Then
  Exit For
End If
Next intRowIndex



If blnFound Then
    MsgBox "Match was found at index " & intMatchIndex
Else
    MsgBox "No Match found"
End If

End Sub
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

When I debug, it stops at this line:

```
   intArray(intRowIndex, intColumnIndex) = Cells(1, Chr(65 + intRowIndex))
```

Giving the error:
Run-time error '9':
Subscript out of range

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing things which quickly causes you to be accessing array values which do not exist.

```
Dim intArray(0, 9) As Integer
```

This means you will have indices (0,0), (0,1), etc. See this picture from the locals toolbar:[image]

But you are incrementing your first index in

```
For intRowIndex = 0 To 9
   intArray(intRowIndex, intColumnIndex)
```

So the second time through the loop, you try to access (1,0) which does not exist.